# DocuSign temporary editor?

Tags: docusignapi

Is it possible to create a temporary user which has the ability to annotate/tag only one document. This user should not have access to anything else in docusign except for that one document.

Alternatively, is it possible to create an editor recipient for a document through an api call, without that user being required to have a docusign account?

Comment: Sure. Normally, any account user can send. Embedded is just a different way to authenticate. Have you tried it? Using the free Developer Sandbox account, you can create additional users within the account with or without admin privileges.

Comment: Yes you're correct. You also made me realize I asked the wrong question. I've updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Per the [docs](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/#editors):

> [Editors have] the same management and access rights for the envelope as the sender and can make changes to the envelope as if they were using the Advanced Correct feature. This recipient can add name and email information, add or change the routing order and set authentication options for the remaining recipients. Additionally, this recipient can edit signature/initial tabs and data fields for the remaining recipients. The recipient must have a DocuSign account to be an editor.

So both Editor recipients and Senders need to have a DocuSign account.

You can programmatically create new users and then delete them, but then you have issues of gaining access to the envelopes that they sent.

In addition, there are business issues: DocuSign users are not sharable.

**Ideas**

1. Depending on your business requirements and situation, you can have a larger number of users, for less cost per user. That way everyone involved in the envelope transactions can be a user and have access/editing privileges as needed. Talk to your sales person.
2. Enable your users to set up the envelope via your software app, not DocuSign. Then your app sends out the envelope. If your app will be sending on behalf of multiple users, you can use the Send On Behalf Of technique.